# ClassNotFoundException of QueryListenOptions

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle, google-cloud-firestore

> After upgrade latest version implementation
>   'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
```

The following code:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Inventory>().setQuery(query, Inventory.class).build();
```

> Inside setQuery(),it shows Cannot resolve symbol 'QueryListenOptions'

How to resolve above issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) explains the change:

> Replaced the `DocumentListenOptions` and `QueryListenOptions` classes
>   with a `MetadataChanges` enum. Instead of calling
>   `addSnapshotListener()` with either of those classes, use the enum:
>
> `addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.INCLUDE, ...)`

As of May 3rd, the Firestore documentation has not yet been updated to include `MetadataChanges`.  For reference, this is the decompiled class file:

```
package com.google.firebase.firestore;

public enum MetadataChanges {
    EXCLUDE,
    INCLUDE;

    private MetadataChanges() {
    }
}
```

**Update**
[FirebaseUI version 3.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases) is built with Firebase SDK version 15.0.0.  It is not compatible with Firestore 16.0.0.  Because you are using FirebaseUI 3.3.1, you must build with Firestore 15.0.0.

Comment: Inside setQuery(),it shows Cannot resolve symbol 'QueryListenOptions'

Comment: it's working but without updating Firebase UI how they publish Firestore 16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same firebase version in all your firebase dependencies

**Edited**

In the last firebase release you don't need to use the same version number.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Thanks to [@Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815718/bob-snyder)

Comment: With the [latest Firebase SDK release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) it is no longer necessary to use the same version number.